# undefined reference to cblas_sgemm

Tags: c++, matrix, linker-errors, cblas

I have the following make file

```
g++ -Wall -O3 -g -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 Matrix.cc -L /usr/lib64/libcblas.so.0 util.cc word_io.cc net_lbl_2reps_scalable.cc train_lbl_2r_ptb.cc -o train_lbl_2r_ptb
```

However I get the error

> /tmp/cc9NLGFL.o: In function `Matrix::scaleAddAB(Matrix const&, Matrix const&, float, float)':
>   /home/ncelm/Matrix.cc:316: undefined reference to`cblas_sgemm'
>   /tmp/cc9NLGFL.o: In function `Matrix::scaleAddAtransB(Matrix const&, Matrix const&, float, float)':
>   /home/ncelm/Matrix.cc:330: undefined reference to`cblas_sgemm'
>   /tmp/cc9NLGFL.o: In function `Matrix::scaleAddABtrans(Matrix const&, Matrix const&, float, float)':
>   /home/ncelm/Matrix.cc:344: undefined reference to`cblas_sgemm'

The function due to which the error is occuring:

```
void Matrix::scaleAddABtrans(const Matrix &A, const Matrix &B, float targetScale, float prodScale)
  {
  assert(A.rows() == rows() && A.cols() == B.cols() && B.rows() == cols());
  ::cblas_sgemm(CblasColMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasTrans,
                A.rows(), B.rows(), A.cols(),
                prodScale, // Scale the product by 1
                A.data(), A.rows(),
                B.data(), B.rows(),
                targetScale, // Scale the target by this before adding the product matrix
                data(), rows());
}
```

It is able to link the file but not find the `sgemm`. Unable to understand why?

Comment: `-L /usr/lib64/libcblas.so.0` doesn't look right to me. Shouldn't it be `-L/usr/lib64 -lcblas`

Answer (score 0):

As user6292850 notes, the `-L` option takes a directory name, not a library name.  To name the library, use `-lcblas`.  You probably don't need to use `-L` in this case, because `/usr/lib64` is likely on the default search path.

One other bit of advice: Put the linker options and the library names *after* any source and object filenames on the command line.  In **make** it would conventionally look something like this:

```
$ c++ $(CXXFLAGS) -o train_lbl_2r_ptb $(SRC) $(LDFLAGS) -lcblas
```

You do that because the linker works its way down the line, as it were, to resolve names.  If, in your example, `util.cc` uses a cblas function, the linker might not find it unless the library appears to the right on the command line.